# Need help - Boolean Logic -Deductive Reasoning

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am trying to self study Probability Theory. Below is an equation that came up from the chapter about Plausible Reasoning.

The goal is to prove that below equation can be deduced to the following: 
C = ( B $ \Rightarrow  \neg A$)

Equation:
[Original Equation directly from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KctD4.png)

[Quote from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANA3r.png)

$C \equiv (A \vee \neg B)(\neg A \vee A \wedge \neg B)  
 \vee \neg A \wedge B ( A \vee B) $

Any idea helps!

Thanks in advanced!

Edit:
Thank you for pointing out that + is not a logical operation. That only shows that I am really unfamiliar with such kind of language.

1.
The book that I am reading is P**robability Theory: The Logic of Science by dwin Thompson Jaynes.**

2. My take is embarrassing to show to the internet. But since you suggested, here is what I have:

$(A \vee \neg B)(\neg A \vee A \wedge \neg B)  \vee \neg A \wedge B ( A \vee B)$

$= (A \neg A) \vee (AA \neg B ) \vee (\neg B \neg A) \vee (\neg B A \neg B) \vee (\neg A B A ) \vee ( \neg A BB) $

$= 0 \vee (A \neg B)  \vee (\neg B \neg A ) \vee (\neg B) \vee 0 \vee (\neg A B) $

= no clue from there..

Edit 2:
I have included actual equation from the book because a lot of professionals in this thread seems to be confused.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) Which textbook are you using/By which methods are you supposed to do he deduction - with a truth table, rewriting using logical equivalences like DeMorgan's law, a tableau, natural deduction, ...? Depending on *how* you are supposed to show the argument, answers will be very different. 2) What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck? Show us some of your own effort. 3) What is $+$ supposed to mean? It is not a logical connective.

Comment: Please review the formula you wrote down. First: you have no logical connective between $(A \lor \neg B)$ and $(\neg A \lor A \land \neg B)$, and likewise between $B$ and $(A \lor B)$ at the end. Now, putting terms next to each other without any explicit operator is often taken to be conjunction ... but you have several explicit $\land$'s as well ... so ... what's going on here?  Also, $(\neg A \lor A \land \neg B)$ really needs parentheses, because $((\neg A \lor A) \land \neg B)$ is not the same as $(\neg A \lor (A \land \neg B))$ ... or did you copy that formula incorrectly?

Comment: Just found a pdf of the book you mention. I note the author uses $A+B$ for disjunction and $AB$ for conjunction. So, I would recommend sticking with that. Indeed, despite what someone apparently told you, the $+$ is a common symbol used in boolean algebras. So, I would recommend getting rid of those $\land$'s and $\lor$'s, and just stick with the notation used in the book.,

Comment: @Bram28 As a newbie, I am still confused as to when to use which set of symbols to mean the same thing. Is '+' used in boolean algebras and '$\cup$ used in logical deduction? Aren't they ( '+' and $\cup$, boolean algebras and logical equations) the same thing? All the big terms here is confusing to me.

Comment: @KeepLearning Understood, ... and don't stress about it!  OK, so the $+$ and $\lor$ are commonly used symbols for boolean algebra / propositional logic. The $\cup$ and $\cap$, however, are decidedly set-theoretic operator.  Although, that said, in probability theory (and that's the book you're looking at), we do interchange between $P(A \land B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $ + = \vee$

Let $$\begin{align} X = B \Rightarrow \neg A 
                    & = \neg B \vee \neg A \\ \end{align}$$

and $$\begin{align} Y & = (A \vee \neg B)\wedge ( \neg A \vee A \wedge \neg B) +\neg A\wedge B \wedge(A \vee B)\\ & = A \wedge \neg B \vee \neg A \wedge\neg B \vee A \wedge \neg B \vee \neg A \wedge B \\ &= \neg A \wedge B \vee A \wedge B \vee A \wedge B \\ & = B \vee A\wedge B \\ & = (\neg B \vee \neg A) \wedge (\neg B \vee B) \\ & = \neg A \vee \neg B \\ & = X \end{align}$$

Note: For the sake of simplicity, I have omitted the step like $ X \wedge \neg X = 0 $

Comment: Thank you Ajay, My apologies due to my unfamiliarity to boolean algebra. ' + ' is 'OR'. Sorry for the confusion again!

Comment: Are you fine with the proof now? @KeepLearning I edited that I too meant "OR" I just came to realize that assumption was typing mistake.